# XSL count of certain elements using a key

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm having trouble getting a total count of elements I look up using a key.

There are `rdf:Description` elements with a type attribute that is '#Concept' or another that is not a concept such as '#A'.

`rdf:Description` elements that are not of type concept have have a child element `hasConcept` with attribute `rdf:resource` that contains a value which corresponds to a the value of the attribute `hasConceptUI/@rdf:resource` of parent `rdf:Description/@:rdf:type` "#A" -as an example-, said `rdf:Descriptions` of that type, have multiple 'hasTerm' elements.

I would like to get a count of these `hasTerm` elements by selecting a specific non-concept `rdf:Description`.

There are multiple `rdf:Description` `rdf:type` "#A" elements. So my problem is that I am only finding the count for each of these descriptions, rather than a count of all of them.

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:key name = "terms" match = "rdf:Description[@rdf:type = '#Concept']" use = "hasConceptUI"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="rdf:RDF/rdf:Description[@rdf:type = '#A']"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match = "rdf:Description[@rdf:type = '#A']">
    <xsl:variable name = "test" select = "key('terms', substring(hasConcept/@rdf:resource, 2))"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$test/hasTerm">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(rdf:Bag/hasTermName/text(), '&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Term Count: ', count($test/hasTerm), ' Position:', position(), '&#xA;', '&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Exclude Classes not matched -->
<xsl:template match="rdf:Description[@rdf:type != '#A']">
</xsl:template>
```

**Sample of XML**

```
<rdf:Description rdf:ID="M0006190" rdf:type="#Concept">
      <hasConceptUI>M0006190</hasConceptUI>
      <hasTerm>
         <rdf:Bag>
            <hasTermUI>T011956</hasTermUI>
            <hasTermName>Diagnostic Imaging</hasTermName>
         </rdf:Bag>
      </hasTerm>
      <hasTerm>
         <rdf:Bag>
            <hasTermUI>T011955</hasTermUI>
            <hasTermName>Imaging, Diagnostic</hasTermName>
         </rdf:Bag>
      </hasTerm>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:ID="D010284" rdf:type="#C">
      <hasParentRecord rdf:resource="#D012480" rdf:type="#C"/>
      <hasConcept rdf:resource="#M0015934"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

Here is a sample of my output currently with the stylesheet above:

```
Abdomen
Abdomens
Abdomen
Term Count: 3 Position:1

Abdominal Muscles
Abdominal Muscle
Muscle, Abdominal
Muscles, Abdominal
Bauchmuskeln
Term Count: 5 Position:2

Abducens Nerve
Nerve, Abducens
Sixth Cranial Nerve
Cranial Nerve, Sixth
Nerve, Sixth Cranial
Nerves, Sixth Cranial
Sixth Cranial Nerves
Nerve VI

(deleted terms here for brevity)
Nerve VIs, Cranial
Nervus abducens
Hirnnerv VI
VI. Hirnnerv
Term Count: 23 Position:3

Abomasum
Abomasums
Labmagen
Term Count: 3 Position:4

Acanthocytes
Acanthocyte
Akanthozyten
Term Count: 3 Position:5
```

Is there anyway I can get a count of all the terms in the document using my key, as opposed to the way it is now only counting the looked up terms per rdf:Description (that are not concepts). I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you restricted to XSLT 1? As the key value is selected with substring it is hard to write that as one expression in XPath 1.0 while in XSLT 2 using XPath 2.0 you can certainly use e.g. `count(//foo/key('key-name', substring(...))/bar)`, that is, call the key function in a step of the path expression.

Comment: If I would not need to change anything else then it is not a restriction

Comment: When I try to use XSLT 2 with your expression, I get the following error: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of
  fn:substring() ("#M0000009", "#M000615276"). Do you know why this happens in XSLT 2 but not XSLT 1?

Comment: Does this happen with `key('terms', substring(hasConcept/@rdf:resource, 2))`? Are there multiple `hasConcept` children? Then rewrite as `key('terms', hasConcept/@rdf:resource/substring(., 2))`. XSLT 1 or XSLT 2 with XSLT 1 backwards compatibility applies string functions to the first selected item while in XSLT 2 it is an error to try to apply them to a sequence of more than one item, you either have to select one explicitly or you call the function on each items as shown, in the last step of a path (or with a `for .. return` if wanted/needed).

Answer (score 1):

I think, if you want to use the key and if you can use at least XSLT 2, then you can select

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:key name = "terms" match = "rdf:Description[@rdf:type = '#Concept']" use = "hasConceptUI"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(rdf:RDF/rdf:Description[@rdf:type = '#A']/key('terms', hasConcept/@rdf:resource/substring(., 2))/hasTerm)"/>

</xsl:template>
```